# PHPExcel doesn't delete last column

Tags: phpexcel

I successfully delete all other blank columns, however, I keep getting a 0 on the last column and last row (everything else in that column is deleted = a few others zero's, except the last one). I've tried to delete it manually `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index)->removeColumn('N', 1);` but it's still there. I've read that this is an issue, but has anyone found a way to correct it?